# What are stereo screenshots for?

Tags: terminology, nvidia-geforce-experience

So I went across one of the few games the Nvidia's Ansel feature supports, and within the many types of capture type it provides, aside from:

> "screenshot", "super resolution" and "360º"

there's also

> "stereo" and "360º stereo".

What "360º stereo" do is take a screenshot and duplicate on top of it, resulting in two rows of the same screenshot being displayed in the same image. As for "stereo" is the same thing, but as two columns.

Note that if you upload a 360 screenshot on facebook, it will automatically become an interactive viewport to scroll around. But for STEREO 360s I can't find anything useful, not even when basically opening it from a casual photo viewer (such as Windows' integrated photo viewer). So what are the so-called "stereo screenshots" (or images) really for?

Comment: Is 'Ansel' a new feature of nVidia GeForce Experience? Or is it a separate application? Just wondering if the [tag:nvidia-geforce-experience] tag is relevant here

Comment: It is. I added it myself, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stereo is, in short description, a name for 3D. It adds depth to the perception.

stereo 360 differs from the known 3D glasses by adding immersion. Any content shown with traditional 3D glasses will look really weird around the edges of the image. Stereo content viewed in a VR headset will surround the viewer in a much more consistent way.

You can read more about stereo 360 and its application in the link below:

https://bigmancgi.com/blog/mono-vs-stereo-vr/